# My HTML5 Video keeps playing when I switch pages

Tags: html, video, reactjs

I am using React and Rails to build a small website with a few different page routes. On the landing page I have included an HTML 5 video, which is muted and autoplays. On this page it works great. However, when I change pages the HTML 5 video continues to play, and is no longer muted (ie. I can hear it playing, but cannot see it). I cannot see the component which contains the video in the DOM.

I think I might need to destroy this component when changing pages, but not exactly sure about the right approach here. Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without providing *any* code, but I am guessing you aren't using lifecycle methods within your components.

Consider using `componentWillUnmount` to destroy/stop the playing video.